# Setting control panel in joomla for admin user

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, access-control, joomla-module

I have a joomla installation with admin and superuser login. I need to set a modules default view page as the control panel page for the admin alone. How can i do the same? Is it possible from the joomla super admin interface or by code?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean you need to set a modules default view? A module only has a single view usually. Is this an admin module or do you mean a component?

Comment: Hi, Also you can check this useful tutorial to understand the Access Control List (ACL) feature in Joomla! https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial